# Problems with date format with MySQL 8.0 String to Date

Tags: mysql

I am facing a strange problem with MySql, I want to convert a String column into a date however when I execute the command below I get an error:

```
UPDATE cauelum.contatos SET Birthday = str_to_date(Birthday, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

[image: terminal-error]

It is basically saying that the correct format is wrong... have you ever had this happen to you before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying day/month/year and it is complaining about a month of 13.  Did you mean `%m/%d/%Y` instead of `%d/%m/%Y`?

Note that an error is only given (instead of str_to_date just returning null) if the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES sql_mode is enabled (which it is by default since I think mysql 5.6); if you want to assume day/month/year but try month/day/year if the former is invalid, you can do:

```
set session sql_mode=replace(@@sql_mode,'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','');
update foo set Birthday=coalesce(str_to_date(Birthday, '%d/%m/%Y'),str_to_date(Birthday, '%m/%d/%Y'));
```

(Though obviously if you have some way to know what the format for each record is, that is much better, since otherwise you may be assuming the wrong format where it is ambiguous.)

Comment: Either that, or the date `12/13/1970` itself is bogus data +1.

Comment: You are correct! but, there is something interesting about this DB apparently if has divergent types of data stored, m/d/y and d/m/y, so I need to first fix that and then run this query! Thanks :D